# Recycling variable name within single function

Tags: variables, g++, conceptual

I have a function that contains two `for` loops, and I'm using a variable called `count` as the counter. I've chosen to recycle the name as the the first loop will finish it's execution  completely before the second one begins, so there is no chance of the counters interfering with each other. The G++ compiler has taken exception to this via the following warning:

```
error: name lookup of ‘count’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping
note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)
```

Is variable recycling considered bad practice in professional software development, or is it a situational concern, and what other implications have I missed here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you doing this?

```
for(int count = 0; ...)
{
    ...
}

for(count = 0; ...)
{
    ...
}
```

I doubt `gcc` would like that, as the second `count` isn't in scope. I think it only applies to the first `for` loop, but `gcc` has options to accept poor code. If you either make the second `int count` or move the first to the outer scope, `gcc` should be happy.

This depends on the circumstances, but I generally don't reuse variables. The name of the variable should reflect its purpose, and switching part way through a function can be confusing. Declare what you need, let the compiler take care of the optimizations.

Comment: This seemed to reproduce the OP's compiler output.  Good call.

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing and your advice fixed the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Steve McConnell recommends not reusing local variables in functions in Code Complete.

He's not the definitive voice of practice in professional software development, but he's about as close as you're going to get to a definitive voice.

The argument is that it makes it harder to read the code.

What are you counting? Name the variables after that.

Comment: Does the name Steve McConnell lend credence? I've not heard of him. Maybe I've been under a rock :) << I wrote this before you added more to your answer. Still wondering why the name is useful here - I think his reasoning is very useful here though so thanks. (We're both edit-updating at the same time. Fun.)

Comment: Code Complete is a book I've been meaning to pick up for a while now. So many of my questions have been answered with quotes from it that I think it's about time I got round to it. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're defining the variable in the for? i.e. "for (int count=0; count++; count < x)"? If so, that could be problematic, as well as unclear. If you're going to use it in a second for loop define it outside both loops.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. The code is now compiled without any errors or warnings. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a loop counter variables like this, then it usually doesn't matter.

```
for (int i ...; ... ; ...) { 
    ... 
}
for (int i ...; ... ; ...) { 
    ... 
}
```

however, if you're intending to shadow another variable:

```
int i ...;
for (int i ...; ... ; ...) { 
    ... 
}
```

that's a red flag.